# FAQ Sidebar on Programmers Meta

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Per the MSE question: [faq-sidebar-for-per-site-metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240186/faq-sidebar-for-per-site-metas) this is to request a FAQ sidebar instead of the chat sidebar on Programmers Meta.

So instead of:

> [image: MPSE frontpage with chat]

We would have a listing of the questions from [faq](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) instead.

And it would look kind of like this<sup>*</sup>:

> [image: MSE frontpage with FAQ]

<sup>*</sup><sub>Note that this example is from MSE, not MPSE</sub>

#### Why?

The FAQ should provide more relevant information to Meta visitors than an invitation to chat would provide.  And putting the FAQ questions on the front page would make them a lot easier to find for first time visitors to Meta.